# ListContourPlot gives fragmented contour plot

Tags: plotting, color, interpolation, data

```
fit=Import["/p/a/t/h/", "Table"];
ListContourPlot[fit, MaxPlotPoints->400, ContourStyle->Directive[Black,Dashed], Contours->100, PlotLegends->Automatic, InterpolationOrder->10]
```

second plot is

```
relax=Import["/p/a/t/h/", "Table"];
ListContourPlot[relax, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> Large, ScalingFunctions -> {"", "", "Log10"}, 
 Contours -> 50, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{1000, 4000}, {0.2, 0.4}, {400, 90000}}]
```

@mjw As your advice I added the code on the question, thank you.

**First plot**
[image]

**Second plot**
[image]

The number of the data is 2400 and the fragmented region has the highest z-values. Is that the reason the plot is fragmented?

Any hints for the problem?

The data is on the link (google drive : (first data) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x-NAD9Vs8wyv9QbDgjcaT9SujHlHChAd and (second data) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hOTWZKpSzm6SHWJVgv40kMFo_b5xVzZr)

UPDATE:
As @mjw 's advice I tried with mesh->None, InterpolationOrder->0 but the resolution of the plot is not good at all. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the link to the data!  If you were to input the *Mathematica* code, rather than show an image, we could better help by starting with your line-of-code.  Otherwise, to help you, each person needs to type in the line.

Comment: Can somebody please explain the best way to import this data into *Mathematica*?

Comment: @mjw  I use this  data=Import["/p/a/t/h/", "Table"];

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was missing the option `"Table"`.

Comment: `InterpolationOrder -> 0` works.  Seems that the data is too disconnected from the other data where there is a dropout.

Comment: Please also try `ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0]` to visualize the data.

Comment: @mjw it works but it is not worth it to do because the resolution for the plot is almost nonsense. :( But thank you for your help.

Comment: I'll post the image as an "answer".

Comment: You can also break up the data into small squares or rectangles to look at it ...

Answer (score 1):

Posting this here because it does not fit in the comments section.  Please see the comments below the question for background.

```
ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, ImageSize -> Large ]
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried but it still gives low resolution and is there are any method to improve the resolution??

Comment: Looks okay on my monitor and on a small "smart" phone.  What display are you using?  What operating system?  Also, suggested in the comments above that you break the data up into smaller rectangles, so that you can zoom in on areas with discontinuities.